# How to get the min/max in a list by using a lambda or function to get a comparison value from the item?

Tags: python, python-2.7, collections, lambda, max

In Python I want to find the max element in a list using a lambda for comparison.

No success with this code:

```
# An 'anonymous' object, like JSON object. Use like: Mock(name='Bob', age=30)
class Mock(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

items = [
    Mock(cost=10, quantity=1),
    Mock(cost=15, quantity=3),
    Mock(cost=20, quantity=5),
    Mock(cost=100, quantity=2)
]

index, value = max(items, key=lambda(item) : item.cost * item.quantity)
print('$%d, q=%d' % (value.cost, value.quantity))
```

I get this error:

```
    index, value = max(items, key=lambda(item) : item.cost * item.quantity)
TypeError: 'Mock' object is not iterable
```

How can I implement this correctly?

Comment: Solved it this (ugly) way:
index, value = max(enumerate(items), key=lambda aTuple : aTuple[1].cost * aTuple[1].quantity)
Not sure it's the most elegant solution.

Comment: Your `max` call is returning the maximum element (by your keyfunc) of items.  It doesn't return an index, value tuple, so it's not surprising that you got the error.  Just try `max([2,3,4])`; you get `4`, not `(2, 4)`.

Comment: @r.pankevicius - you should write that as an answer (with explanation). I wrote it up & realized you already put it as a comment. I don't think it's ugly, it's the right way IMHO.

Comment: @Corley - it's unf**kingreadable...

Answer (score 8):

If you don't need the index, you can use the result directly:

```
value = max(items, key=lambda(item) : item.cost * item.quantity)
print value.cost, value.quantity
```

`max` returns the actual max item, which is a `Mock` instance. You can't unpack it into two items.

If you really want the index, you can either find it, or modify your search a little bit to decorate the index into the item:

```
index, value = max(enumerate(items), key=lambda(item): item[1].cost * item[1].quantity)
```

First, we convert the original list into a second list where each item is a tuple of (index, value). Then, the key also has to change, because instead of `item.cost`, `item` is now an `(index, MockItem)` pair, and so you need to get `item[1]`, then get the attributes. Don't forget to unpack the result into index and value to get both.

Comment: Corley, it's f**kingreadable and it works.
value = max(items, key=lambda(item) : item.cost * item.quantity)
That's the answer, please put it, I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most efficient way but it's easy for anyone reading it to understand. If you have very large lists, let me know and I'll point you to more efficient solutions.

```
# get the value
max_item = max(items, key=lambda item: item.cost * item.quantity)
# get the index
max_item_index = items.index(max_item)
```

If you also want the calculated value, then just do a loop to keep it clear:

```
max_value = max_index = max_item = None
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    value = item.cost * item.quantity
    if (max_value is None) or (value > max_value):
        max_value = value
        max_index = i
        max_item = item

if max_value is not None:
    print max_index, max_value, max_item
```

Comment: This:
# get the value
max_item = max(items, key=lambda item: item.cost * item.quantity)
doesn't work in Python 2.7. Do you use Python 3?

Comment: Sorry, you were right. There is a difference between 'value=somefunc()' and 'index, value = somefunc()' in Python.